# configuration of zend frame work in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, zend-framework

I have created a project zfapi by zf command in ubuntu.

Now http://mysite.com/path/to/zfapi/

gives me listing of folder public application and others.

http://mysite.com/path/to/zfapi/public give me the index page index.php.

and i have made the UserController.php in application/controllers

but by http://mysite.com/path/to/zfapi/user/

is saying user not found.

what configuration i need to set for running it proper.

This is my default file in site-available

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin myeamil 

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>


<Directory /var/www/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride Limit
    </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Please suggest how should i set my configualtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having created your project with `zf.sh create project`, please have a look at the README.txt file located in the docs folder of your project.

You will find an example of virtual host which should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

  <Directory /var/www/mysite/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Create a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with this virtual host, and activate this site using `a2ensite`.

Comment: I have already running  dns mysite.com so how can i do ?

Comment: Would you like please to explain how the URL to access your ZF project should look like? In my answer, I assumed you wanted to access it at http://mysite.com/